# Deploy JHipster Created Spring boot App on WildFly faces the problems

Tags: java, spring-boot, wildfly, jhipster

I've created spring boot using JHipster and it is working with its own embedded Web application (Tomcat). Now I want to deploy into Jboss/Wildfly 13.0. 
This is the POM config of my app, deleted the Build tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>ir.isc.obh</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>api_manager</name>

    <properties>
        <argLine>-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx256m</argLine>
        <assertj.version>3.6.2</assertj.version>
        <awaitility.version>2.0.0</awaitility.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.5</commons-io.version>
        <commons-lang.version>3.5</commons-lang.version>
        <docker-maven-plugin.version>0.4.13</docker-maven-plugin.version>
        <!-- Overridden to get metrics-jcache -->
        <dropwizard-metrics.version>3.2.2</dropwizard-metrics.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.8.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hikaricp.version>2.6.0</hikaricp.version>
        <ibm.mq.version>0.0.4</ibm.mq.version>
        <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.7.9</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jhipster.server.version>1.1.9</jhipster.server.version>
        <liquibase-hibernate5.version>3.6</liquibase-hibernate5.version>
        <liquibase-slf4j.version>2.0.0</liquibase-slf4j.version>
        <logstash-logback-encoder.version>4.11</logstash-logback-encoder.version>
        <lombok-version>1.18.0</lombok-version>
        <m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>
        <mapstruct.version>1.1.0.Final</mapstruct.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.6.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-enforcer-plugin.version>1.4.1</maven-enforcer-plugin.version>
        <maven-resources-plugin.version>3.0.1</maven-resources-plugin.version>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddHHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.version>3.0.0</maven.version>
        <metrics-spring.version>3.1.3</metrics-spring.version>
        <node.version>v6.11.1</node.version>
        <!-- These remain empty unless the corresponding profile is active -->
        <profile.no-liquibase />
        <profile.swagger />
        <prometheus-simpleclient.version>0.0.20</prometheus-simpleclient.version>
        <!-- Sonar properties -->
        <project.testresult.directory>${project.build.directory}/test-results</project.testresult.directory>
        <run.addResources>false</run.addResources>
        <scala-maven-plugin.version>3.2.2</scala-maven-plugin.version>
        <scala.version>2.12.1</scala.version>
        <sonar-maven-plugin.version>3.2</sonar-maven-plugin.version>

        <sonar.exclusions>src/main/webapp/content/**/*.*, src/main/webapp/bower_components/**/*.*, src/main/webapp/i18n/*.js, target/www/**/*.*</sonar.exclusions>

        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria>S3437,UndocumentedApi,BoldAndItalicTagsCheck</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria>

        <!-- Rule https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=Web%3ABoldAndItalicTagsCheck is ignored. Even if we agree that using the "i" tag is an awful practice, this is what is recommended by http://fontawesome.io/examples/ -->
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.BoldAndItalicTagsCheck.resourceKey>src/main/webapp/app/**/*.*</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.BoldAndItalicTagsCheck.resourceKey>
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.BoldAndItalicTagsCheck.ruleKey>Web:BoldAndItalicTagsCheck</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.BoldAndItalicTagsCheck.ruleKey>
        <!-- Rule https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS3437 is ignored, as a JPA-managed field cannot be transient -->
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.S3437.resourceKey>src/main/java/**/*</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.S3437.resourceKey>
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.S3437.ruleKey>squid:S3437</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.S3437.ruleKey>
        <!-- Rule http://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AUndocumentedApi is ignored, as we want to follow "clean code" guidelines and classes, methods and arguments names should be self-explanatory -->
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.UndocumentedApi.resourceKey>src/main/java/**/*</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.UndocumentedApi.resourceKey>
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.UndocumentedApi.ruleKey>squid:UndocumentedApi</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.UndocumentedApi.ruleKey>

        <sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.testresult.directory}/coverage/jacoco/jacoco-it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.testresult.directory}/coverage/jacoco/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
        <sonar.java.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.codeCoveragePlugin>

        <sonar.javascript.jstestdriver.reportsPath>${project.testresult.directory}/karma</sonar.javascript.jstestdriver.reportsPath>
        <!-- For Sonar < 6.2 -->
        <sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath>${project.testresult.directory}/coverage/report-lcov/lcov.info</sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath>
        <!-- For Sonar >= 6.2 -->
        <sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths>${project.testresult.directory}/coverage/report-lcov/lcov.info</sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths>

        <sonar.sources>${project.basedir}/src/main/</sonar.sources>
        <sonar.surefire.reportsPath>${project.testresult.directory}/surefire-reports</sonar.surefire.reportsPath>
        <sonar.tests>${project.basedir}/src/test/</sonar.tests>

        <!-- Spring properties -->
        <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
        <!--<spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RC1</spring-cloud.version>-->
        <springfox.version>2.7.0</springfox.version>
        <validation-api.version>1.1.0.Final</validation-api.version>
        <yarn.version>v0.27.5</yarn.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.iban4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>iban4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jms -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-rev-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${ibm.mq.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.jhipster</groupId>
            <artifactId>jhipster</artifactId>
            <version>${jhipster.server.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Metrics Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-annotation</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard-metrics.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-json</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard-metrics.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard-metrics.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard-metrics.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-servlets</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ryantenney.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${metrics-spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson Binding -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hppc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-afterburner</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
            <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
            <version>57.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web App COnfig -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Config to deploy on WildFly; Just uncomment it -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Doc Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Persistence Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Change Log Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mattbertolini</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase-slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Features -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>${logstash-logback-encoder.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Cloud Dependencies -->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-spectator</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-ribbon</artifactId>
            <!-- netty's native is pulled, but is useless unless you explicitly add the native binary dependency.
                 Having it in the classpath without the binary can cause warnings -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-transport-native-epoll</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <version>${awaitility.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <!-- parent POM declares this dependency in default (compile) scope -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- jhipster-needle-maven-add-dependency -->
    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>no-liquibase</id>
            <properties>
                <profile.no-liquibase>,no-liquibase</profile.no-liquibase>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>swagger</id>
            <properties>
                <profile.swagger>,swagger</profile.swagger>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <filesets>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>target/www/</directory>
                                </fileset>
                            </filesets>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>true</executable>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-info</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                 <!--log configuration-->
                <logback.loglevel>INFO</logback.loglevel>
                 <!--default Spring profiles-->
                <spring.profiles.active>prod${profile.swagger}${profile.no-liquibase}</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

During the deployment I get this issue that it cannot instantiate the WebApplicationInitializer class.

```
"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./api" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: ir.isc.OauthServerApp
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ir.isc.OauthServerApp.<init>()"},
```

Comment: did you try this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222441/how-to-solve-failed-to-instantiate-webapplicationinitializer-class

Comment: go through this link : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/522