# Apache Tiles with Spring MVC giving error - Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

Heyy coders...I was setting up Apache tiles and was configuring the java & xml classes..But now when i am starting the server i am getting an error like..please help me to solve this issue and my tiles also not working ..

```
    SEVERE: Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5139)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getSingleton(LoggerFactory.java:223)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:120)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:111)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:269)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:131)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.context.AbstractContextLoaderInitializer.<init>(AbstractContextLoaderInitializer.java:44)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.<init>(AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.java:60)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.<init>(AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.java:42)
    at com.wanclik.config.AppInitializer.<init>(AppInitializer.java:8)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:152)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1363)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1186)
    ... 47 more
```

My java Classes are..

1. Appconfig.java

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebMvc
   @EnableAsync
   @ComponentScan( basePackages = "com.wanclik" )
   public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
       /**
        * Configure TilesConfigurer.
        */
       @Bean
       public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer(){
           TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
           tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(new String[] {"/WEB- 
       INF/pages/tiles/tiles.xml"});
           tilesConfigurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
           return tilesConfigurer;
       }

       /**
        * Configure ViewResolvers to deliver preferred views.
        */
       @Override
       public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
           TilesViewResolver viewResolver = new TilesViewResolver();
           registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
       }

       /**
        * Configure ResourceHandlers to serve static resources like CSS/ Javascript etc...
        */

       @Override
       public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
           registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
       }

   }
   ```

2.AppInitializer.java

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }

}
```

XML files are..

1.Web.xml

```
    <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>SEO Rest APIs</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

2.mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.wanclik" />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:*.properties" />
    <util:properties id="props" location="classpath:*.properties" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/pages/tiles/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
</beans>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve "Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222441/how-to-solve-failed-to-instantiate-webapplicationinitializer-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the logs it shows that org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder class not found so please ensure that you have dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i have added that portion in pom.xml now its showing "Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration'"

Any idea??